# Web Services iPhone - Remote Database

Tags: iphone, mysql, web-services

I know that web services are the way forward for an iPhone App to communicate with a remote MYSQL database but how can I find out how to build one? Can anybody recommend any resources which can help me learn how to construct such a service, preferably using PHP...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web services are not only way to communicate with server, You can communicate with remote mySQL database, using API. API is an interface that communicates with server and device.

Device will pass parameters in POST/GET method in request, API will fetch that parameter and work accordingly and connect to mysql database if necessary and will return the output in any format (XML/JSON or simple string).

Hope This helps.

Comment: Where can I find tutorials for the iphone?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/10/29/iphone-coding-tutorial-creating-an-online-leaderboard-for-your-games/